# Webdriver doesn't stable and sometimes crashes during the running

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, automation, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

Sometimes the webDriver stopped during the running and warn about "no session"/ "no window target" and etc..

I've used Protractor on Node.JS for my automated testing.

The errors are not Constantine and sometimes all the 200 test cases are work fine until the end of the running.

**Error:**

```
10:38:20.745 INFO - Executing: [get current url])
10:38:20.766 INFO - Done: [get current url]
10:38:20.799 INFO - Executing: [take screenshot])
10:38:21.299 INFO - Done: [take screenshot]
10:38:22.002 INFO - Executing: [get: http://app.vcita.com/auth/login])
10:38:27.870 INFO - Done: [get: http://app.vcita.com/auth/login]
10:38:29.917 INFO - Executing: [find elements: By.cssSelector: [ng-click="connectWithGoogle()"]])
10:38:30.009 INFO - Done: [find elements: By.cssSelector: [ng-click="connectWithGoogle()"]]
10:38:30.049 INFO - Executing: [is enabled: 762 [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (4c9896194733dc6b787bf75f84f48ec2)] -> css selector: [ng-click="connectWithGoogle()"]]])
10:38:30.148 INFO - Done: [is enabled: 762 [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (4c9896194733dc6b787bf75f84f48ec2)] -> css selector: [ng-click="connectWithGoogle()"]]]
10:38:30.243 INFO - Executing: [find elements: By.cssSelector: [ng-click="connectWithGoogle()"]])
10:38:30.341 INFO - Done: [find elements: By.cssSelector: [ng-click="connectWithGoogle()"]]
10:38:30.387 INFO - Executing: [is displayed: 762 [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (4c9896194733dc6b787bf75f84f48ec2)] -> css selector: [ng-click="connectWithGoogle()"]]])
10:38:30.467 INFO - Done: [is displayed: 762 [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (4c9896194733dc6b787bf75f84f48ec2)] -> css selector: [ng-click="connectWithGoogle()"]]]
10:38:30.523 INFO - Executing: [find elements: By.cssSelector: [ng-click="connectWithGoogle()"]])
10:38:30.569 INFO - Done: [find elements: By.cssSelector: [ng-click="connectWithGoogle()"]]
10:38:30.613 INFO - Executing: [click: 762 [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (4c9896194733dc6b787bf75f84f48ec2)] -> css selector: [ng-click="connectWithGoogle()"]]])
10:38:30.760 INFO - Done: [click: 762 [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (4c9896194733dc6b787bf75f84f48ec2)] -> css selector: [ng-click="connectWithGoogle()"]]]
10:38:32.812 INFO - Executing: [get window handles])
10:38:32.842 INFO - Done: [get window handles]
10:38:34.873 INFO - Executing: [get window handles])
10:38:34.908 INFO - Done: [get window handles]
10:38:34.961 INFO - Executing: [switch to window: CDwindow-FC9091C4-87E2-45A2-B125-D658EADF49ED])
10:38:35.009 INFO - Done: [switch to window: CDwindow-FC9091C4-87E2-45A2-B125-D658EADF49ED]
10:38:35.037 INFO - Executing: [find elements: By.id: choose-account-0])
10:38:38.163 WARN - Exception thrown
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElements(RemoteWebDriver.java:386)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementsById(RemoteWebDriver.java:397)
        at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElements(By.java:206)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElements(RemoteWebDriver.java:340)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver$2.invoke(EventFiringWebDriver.java:101)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.findElements(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver.findElements(EventFiringWebDriver.java:173)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.FindElements.call(FindElements.java:49)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.FindElements.call(FindElements.java:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:168)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
10:38:38.454 WARN - Exception: null
10:38:39.551 INFO - Executing: [take screenshot])
10:38:39.584 WARN - Exception thrown
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: no such window: target window already closed
from unknown error: web view not found
  (Session info: chrome=48.0.2564.109)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.14.313457 (3d645c400edf2e2c500566c9aa096063e707c9cf),platform=Windows NT 10.0 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 22 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-26 23:59:50'
System info: host: 'vCitaQA', ip: '10.0.0.5', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_65'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, chrome={userDataDir=C:\Users\idan\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir9468_8071}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=48.0.2564.109, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 4c9896194733dc6b787bf75f84f48ec2
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:622)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.getScreenshotAs(RemoteWebDriver.java:324)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.CaptureScreenshot.call(CaptureScreenshot.java:35)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.CaptureScreenshot.call(CaptureScreenshot.java:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:168)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
10:38:39.965 WARN - Exception: no such window: target window already closed
from unknown error: web view not found
  (Session info: chrome=48.0.2564.109)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.14.313457 (3d645c400edf2e2c500566c9aa096063e707c9cf),platform=Windows NT 10.0 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 22 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-26 23:59:50'
System info: host: 'vCitaQA', ip: '10.0.0.5', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_65'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, chrome={userDataDir=C:\Users\idan\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir9468_8071}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=48.0.2564.109, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 4c9896194733dc6b787bf75f84f48ec2
```

Please help me to figure out why it happens and what the better solution to avoid it..

Thanks.

Comment: Is this happening in Chrome only? Have you tried in Firefox? Have you tried upgrading Protractor? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @alecxe, actually IDK because I can't use FF anymore, There some problem with the latest version and the protractor can't run on this browser now.. I should solve this problem as well. IE works slowly when typing and it delay the running.So, probably it doesn;t happen only by Chrome, but I don't  sure about it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the `chromedriver` [changelog](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.14/notes.txt), `chromedriver` 2.14 which you are using supports Chrome 39-42. I suspect there might be compatibility issues in your case because Chrome is brand new (version 48), but `chromedriver` is outdated.

Please upgrade `Protractor` to the, preferably, latest version and then run `webdriver-manager update` to update `chromedriver` as well.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using chromedriver 2.14 please use chrome v39.0. The protractor version as 1.64. 
This will solve your problem.